# Kivy+Python apk Mysql Remote Database access

Tags: android, mysql, python-3.x, kivy

Scenario: Buildozer packaged python apk works fine on Android Emulator and shows Login screen. On hitting Login button I am getting details of logged in user from Mysql database

MySql database server is a Ubuntu chromebook. Android Emulator is on Windows machine.
I can access the database via from Windows machine using HeidiSql - i.e ip address and user name / password @ port 3306.

However the app running on the emulator gives a permission denied error

Please advise how I can find root cause of the issue and rectify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening because the buildozer spec file was missing the option

android.permissions = INTERNET

After putting this the sql queries started working.